# Use of Logical Masks

Tags: matlab

I working on a homework assignment and trying to solve the following problem:

[image]

Here is the code I have so far:

```
function [ ] = Activity45( Time )
%Homework 4
%Activity 4.5

t=Time;

A=[0:0.1:t];
B=3*exp(-(A/3)).*sin(pi.*A);
C=(B>0);

plot(A,B(C))

end
```

So I am trying to use a mask to extract the data from Matrix B in Matrix C. But I do not know how to match the data up between A and C, to then use plot().

Any help?

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much, right after I posted the question I thought to my self to try to plot A(C), B(C).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `plot(A(C), B(C))` you don't get the intended curve because you don't have values equal to zero. Instead the last two points to the left and right are connected with a line above 0. The right way would be to set the value on the Y-Axis to zero.

```
B(~C)=0;
plot(A,B);
```

For future formulas, it might be a good idea to use variable names matching the variable names in your formulas.